# Xcode Class AXAccessQueue is implemented in both

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10

When I create a new project in Xcode and launch it. The next error appears in the logs:

> objc[21022]: Class **AXAccessQueue** is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities (0x122377780) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accessibility.framework/Frameworks/AXHearingSupport.framework/AXHearingSupport (0x123f2d888). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   objc[21022]: Class **AXAccessQueueTimer** is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities (0x122374d50) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accessibility.framework/Frameworks/AXHearingSupport.framework/AXHearingSupport (0x123f2d8d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   ```

I'm searching for ways to fix it properly, not just disabling it. 
Can someone please explain to me what this is and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: And I have this issue everytime, so I create a new project, do nothing and this happens

Comment: So this happens even when you open a blank project? Can you upload that new project?

Comment: Sure. Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6p0oybvwdyk4bp/test.zip?dl=0

Comment: So it happens when I open the simulator. The app starts and after some seconds I get this message

Comment: I added a label to the view controller and it seems to be running fine. When you installed Xcode did you drag it into Applications folder?

Comment: I installed it via the AppStore, so it's automatically in it

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page. Are you running High Sierra? and XCode 10? Have you restarted your machine? If all that is true, then I'd try deleting XCode and reinstalling because it's a totally blank page. It should work.

Comment: Annoying Xcode... having same issue